# unable to make the make file

Tags: objective-c, gnustep

Hi Sir first of all i would like to thank you for answering me .
still i am stuck up with an error
when i type

include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

in the MINGW32 shell i am getting the error as follows

sh: GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES: command not found
sh: include: command not found

please tell me whether i should make a make.txtfile and type make  in MINGW32 shell or a make.mfile in MINGW32 shell

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you are trying to run the make file as a shell script, that's what the error message suggests. This might be trivial, but you need to invoke `make` to "execute" the contents of the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

possibly you are calling the Windows version of make.exe because system32 or another build system is in your path. Reorder PATH to make sure mingw32/bin is first.

Answer (score 1):

If you use GNUstep on windows you probably better install  cygwin also. Than you start the bash shell, source the provided file to get all the GNUSTEP pathes and than you will have more luck. Currently it seems you are starting from the cmd.exe  and  well you do not have any Shell installed so the stuff always will broke. You really have to follow the  installation guidelines and must not forget this step. (this needs a unix shell)

http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/User/GNUstep/gnustep-howto_4.html#SEC8

So really you must follow the outlines here
http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/User/GNUstep/gnustep-howto_toc.html

Regards
Friedrich